# I can't run this code of coverting an array into a list

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert an array into a list.
Below is the code :

```
void tab2list(int n, list **T) {
    int t[z];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Entrez l'element %d du tableau\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &t[i]);
        insert_end(t[i], &T);
    }
}
```

and this is how I call it in the `main` function:

```
tab2list(n, &tete);
```

Comment: please tell us whats the output here, and what is your desired output.

Comment: well I input an array and the output is a linked list

Comment: `insert_end(t[i], &T);` is probably  a mistake, although impossible to say since you did not post any details about how your list works

Comment: well, i just want to create an array first, then when it's created, it copies every element in that array to a singly linked list.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The emphasis is on minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition for the array is incorrect, it should be:

```
int t[n];
```

Note that you do not need to declare a local array for your purpose, but you should check for proper conversion by `scanf`.

Note also that `insert_end` probably does not take a `list ***` argument.

Here is an improved version:

```
void tab2list(int n, list **T) {
    int i, res, value;
    for (i = 0; i < n;) {
        printf("Entrez l'element %d du tableau\n", i + 1);
        res = scanf("%d", &value);
        if (res == 1) {
            insert_end(value, T);
            i++;
        } else 
        if (res == -1) {
            printf("fin de fichier inattendue\n");
            break;
        } else {
            scanf("%*s"); /* skip the offending input */
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to perform some extra checks on the values before inserting them into the list, you can split the code in 2 loops:

```
void tab2list(int n, list **T) {
    int i, res, t[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n;) {
        printf("Entrez l'element %d du tableau\n", i + 1);
        res = scanf("%d", &t[i]);
        if (res == 1) {
            i++;
        } else 
        if (res == -1) {
            printf("fin de fichier inattendue\n");
            return;
        } else {
            scanf("%*s"); /* skip the offending input and try again */
        }
    }
    /* perform some extra checks on the array... */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        insert_end(t[i], &T);
    }
}
```

**EDIT** after you gave further information on your actual problem, here is a fixed version:

```
#define z 50
struct list {
    int val;
    struct list *next;
};
typedef struct list list;

void tab2list(int *t, int n, list **T) {
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         insert_end(t[i], T);
     }
}

int main(void) {
    int n, i;
    int t[z];
    list *tete = NULL;
    printf("Entrez le nb d'element de ton tableau(max 50)\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Entrez l'element %d du tableau\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &t[i]);
    }
    tab2list(t, n, &tete);
    afficher_list(tete);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it seems you didn't quite get my question well, what i was is to create a full array for once, then browser it and copy it into a list

Comment: @D.Mouttie: This intent was not apparent from your code.  You are inserting each element into the list just after parsing it from `stdin`.  It is easy to split the code in 2 phases: one loop for parsing the input and another to insert values into the list.

Comment: it doesn't work, it just fails when i enter the elements

Comment: @D.Mouttie: how does it *fail*? what is the value of `n`? how many elements do you enter?  What does it print?

Comment: #define z 50

struct list
{
    int val;
    struct list* next;
} ;
typedef struct list list;

void tab2list(int t,list **T)
 {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            insert_end(t,&T);
        }

    }


main ()
{
int n,i;
int t[z];
list* tete=NULL;

 printf("Entrez le nb d'element de ton tableau(max 50)\n");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            for (i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            printf("Entrez l'element %d du tableau\n",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&t[i]);
            }
tab2list(t,&tete);
afficher_list(tete);
}

Comment: @D.Mouttie: Why did you not post the whole code before? `tab2list` should be passed the array and number of elements, it does not read the elements, `main` does.  The code should be easy to derive from the above answer.

Comment: how to pass the array, as t[i] or t ?

Comment: @D.Mouttie: `tab2list(t, n, &tete);`

Comment: is there a way to pm someone here?

Comment: @D.Mouttie: I updated the answer with a corrected version of your code.  There are still many issues with error checking and missing prototypes and missing code for the list handling functions, that may have problems too.

Comment: that solved my problem thanks a lot, now i know where i was making the fault

Comment: further question, in that insert_end why did you send T and not &T ?

Comment: @D.Mouttie: I am guessing `insert_end` prototype.  It should take a `list **` argument, the address of the pointer to the initial list element. It needs the address to modify the pointer in case the list is empty. `tab2list` receives `&tete` for the very same reason.  Passing `T` is the logical way.  You should post the prototypes for all functions used in your code.

Comment: actually my code worked properly i was just wondering why because i kept passing &T instead of T, anyway here're the prototypes : 
void tab2list(int *t,list **T)
void insert_end(int v,list **T)
void inserer_debut(int v,list **T)

Comment: @D.Mouttie: what is the prototype for `insert_end`?  Unless `T` is an array, passing `&T` or `T` is not equivalent.  Only one can *work properly* depending on the prototype and implementation of `insert_end`

Comment: i posted it, am i allowed to post emails here? it's better to send you the whole code ^^

Comment: @D.Mouttie: where did you post the code? Just the `main` function and the list handling functions are needed.

Comment: i will do it tomorow, anyway i changed it a bkt and it's working as i wanted it work

Comment: <pre><code> struct list
{
    int val;
    struct list* next;
} ;
typedef struct list list;
void afficher_list(list *T)
void insert_end(int v,list **T)
void tab2list(int *t, list **T)
    {
        insert_end(t,T);
    }
main ()
{
int n,i;
int t[z];
list* tete=NULL;

 printf("Entrez le nb d'element de ton tableau(max 50)\n");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            for (i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            printf("Entrez l'element %d du tableau\n",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&t[i]);
            tab2list(t[i],&tete);
            }
afficher_list(tete);
}

</code></pre>

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
int t[z];
```

to

```
int t[n];
```

as I don't think your program will compile, as the variable  `z` is not declared.

Also, I think you want to read the number of elements you want to be in the table, so for that, you need to create an array of that size to hold the numbers. So `t[n]`.

---

As @chqrlie said, check for the failure of `scanf`.

Comment: it did compile, i didn't post the whole code since it's quite long, 200 lines, the only thing not working is this

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether variable `z` is defined and if so then how it is defined. For example the function does not contain a check that at least `n <= z`.

Moreover I think that the second parameter of function `insert_end` has type `list **`. So it should be called like

```
insert_end( t[i], T );
```

because variable `T` already has type `list **`.

But in any case the function definition does not make a great sense.
I think that the array should be passed to the function as an argument.

So the function can look the following way

```
void tab2list( list **T, int a[], int n ) 
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) insert_end( a[i], T ); 
}
```